# What is this colored ring effect on my computer screen?

Tags: optics, everyday-life

I found rainbows on my computer screen. I can glimpse some faint color if I look at the screen from the side at a sharp angle.
It is a lot more obvious when I reflect it off a dark surface (shown here, on a black electric water heater).

What is it?

[image]

Comment: https://physicsworld.com/a/using-pictures-to-describe-light/

Comment: Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/417927/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/397802/123208

Comment: Looks like [Newton rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_rings),- an interference pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Your colored rings are part of a bullseyes pattern that can be seen in some smartphones and tablets with a birefringent layer in the screen, if the screen is viewed through a linear polarizing filter (A). The same effect appears if the reflection in a dark surface is seen, because the shiny surface behaves like a linear polarizing filter (B). See [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/397802/reflection-of-phone-screen-light-in-a-window/685759#685759)

[image: photo of bullseyes pattern]