Why am I getting these circular fringes?
Just to describe the picture , I have my ipad (with a screen protector glass on it) and the light from the screen is being reflected from my smartphone's screen.

Interestingly we can see some circular colored fringes forming after the reflection which is something I have never seen before. I do know about patterns forming from reflection (e.g thin film interference) but I am not sure this one is similar to that.
So can someone point out why am I getting these "circular fringes" after reflection ?

Some of you might suggest that it is happening because my smartphone has a glass cover too but I don't think that is involved here because I got similar pattern from other surfaces that were able to reflect the light from the ipad to my eyes.

See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/397802/123208 & links therein. Also https://xkcd.com/1814/ and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/417927/123208
